# node.js + Object Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app i have to construct an object array from another object array.

Consider my object array as..

```
[ { id_0: 356, id_1: 33, name_1: 'aaaa' },
  { id_0: 756, id_1: 89, name_1: 'bbbbb' },
  { id_0: 456, id_1: 89, name_1: 'ccccc' },
  { id_0: 356, id_1: 27, name_1: 'dddd' } ]
```

I have to construct an object array as like below:

```
[{
"356":["33":"aaaa","27":"ddddd"],------------->Changes made
"456":[{"89":"cccc"}],
"756":[{"89":"bbbbbbbb"}]
}]
```

I tried using async.map.But i  cant get the right way to do it.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the point of using `async` here?

Comment: It is `Array.map()` not `async.map()` and you don't usually call it that way, but as a method on an instance of an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function, like this

```
console.log(data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    var obj = {};
    result[current.id_0] = result[current.id_0] || [];
    obj[current.id_1] = current.name_1;
    result[current.id_0].push(obj);
    return result
}, {}));
```

**Output**

```
{ '356': [ { '33': 'aaaa' }, { '27': 'dddd' } ],
  '456': [ { '89': 'ccccc' } ],
  '756': [ { '89': 'bbbbb' } ] }
```

If you want to convert this to an array of object, just wrap the result of `data.reduce` with `[]` like this

```
console.log([data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    ...
    ...
}, {})]);
```

**Edit:**

```
result[current.id_0] = result[current.id_0] || [];
```

this line makes sure that `result[current.id_0]` is an array. If the value of `result[current.id_0]` is truthy, then that value is rturned but if it is not, then `[]` will be returned. So, a new array will be created and assigned to `result[current.id_0]`. It is actually a shorthand for

```
if (result.hasOwnProperty(current.id_0) === false) {
    result[current.id_0] = [];
}
```

**Edit 2:** If you like to keep the grouped elements as an object, you could do like this

```
console.log(data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result[current.id_0] = result[current.id_0] || {};
    result[current.id_0][current.id_1] = current.name_1;
    return result
}, {}));
```

**Output**

```
{ '356': { '27': 'dddd', '33': 'aaaa' },
  '456': { '89': 'ccccc' },
  '756': { '89': 'bbbbb' } }
```

Comment: @Subburaj Please check the edit and let me know if you need more clarifications :)

Comment: @Subburaj Did you mean `{"33":"aaaa","27":"ddddd"}`? Because that would be very appropriate here?

Comment: @ thefourtheye  one more thing.. Don't thing that i am outsourcing everything to you..I am new to this stuff thats y i have idea where to start.. See my edited post..

Comment: @Subburaj I just checked, but I don't see any updates.

Comment: @Subburaj I am sorry, now the question gets too specific and the original question is entirely different from this one. Can you please post that as a new question?

Comment: @Subburaj Thanks for understanding :) I am restoring the question now.

Comment: @ thefourtheye  see this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955564/node-js-objectarray"